# When I added google anayltics to my site, it now won't load images

Tags: php, html, google-analytics

Here is the code for the images

I am using Joomla and Jumi - I have had issues with pre defined items with jumi before, and wondering if it has something to do with that?

```
  <?php

include("settings.php");

    mysql_connect($loginURL,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("-9");

  $cardUUID = $_GET['id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM card WHERE UUID='{$cardUUID}'";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  if (!$result) {  
  echo 'Could not run result query: ' . mysql_error();    echo $sql; exit;  }

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  header("Content-type: image/jpg");
   if(base64_decode($row['cardimage']) == false)
        echo $row['cardimage'];
    else
        echo base64_decode($row['cardimage']); 


?>
```

and here is the GA code I added

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-243-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: The php file seems to generate image content. You can't add Javascript to it. It's either a page with javascript or an image. You can't have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The main problem is when you use base64decode.

you need to change this `echo base64_decode($row['cardimage']);` line with `file_get_contents($row['cardimage']);`

[Online demo](http://goo.gl/QzRFKe)

Here the code

```
<?php
//In this example I am going to use hard code cardimage data
$row['cardimage'] = "data:image/png;base64,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";

header("Content-type: image/png");
if(base64_decode($row['cardimage']) == false)
    echo $row['cardimage'];
else
    echo file_get_contents($row['cardimage']); 
?>
```